# How many database or table needed for Event sourcing?

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm trying to use event sourcing, ddd and cqrs.
I can't understand that I have to create two database (or table) ( 1-json 2-normalize database) or one database (just json)
And also if I have create two database (or table), I have to save data in databases (json and normalize) as atomic in one transaction or not?
Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't understand that I have to create two database (or table) ( 1-json 2-normalize database) or one database (just json)

It's possible to get by with just an event store and nothing else.

"get by" isn't necessarily pleasant, however.  Event stores are, as a rule, really good at "append new information", but not particularly good at "query".  Thus, the usual answer is to deploy processes that copy information from your event store to something that has nicer query support.

> I have to save data in databases (json and normalize) as atomic in one transaction or not?

It's a common pattern to update the event storage only, and then later invoke the process to copy the information from the event storage to your query support.  Of course, that also means that your queries may end up showing old/out of date information (here is the answer to your question as-of five minutes ago).

If you store your query friendly data model with the event storage (tables in the same relational database, for instance), then you can arrange for at least some of your updates to the query friendly model to be synchronized with the events.

In other words, you get trade offs, not a single cookie cutter pattern that is used everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

## DDD

We're making an assumption here that you fully understand using DDD and the implications. Specifically related to Event Sourcing, it's a matter of defining Aggregate boundaries and the events that become their state.

## CQRS

Again we're making an assumption that you fully understand the implications. CQRS merely *allows* you to write code in vertical slices (i.e. from UI to database) for handling "commands" separately from code that handles "queries". That's all. While it's true that you can then take this further, by storing data in a "read model" that might even be in a different database, let alone table, it's not a requirement of implementing CQRS.

As CQRS pertains to Event Sourcing - it's a good fit because the data model you tend to end up with in Event Sourcing is not conducive to complex queries. It's typically limited to "get the Aggregate by it's ID". Therefore having "projections" to store the data in other ways that are more appropriate for querying and loading into UIs is the typical approach.

## Event Sourcing

If you implement a Domain Model in such a way that every command handled by an Aggregate (i.e. every use-case/task carried out by a user) generates one or more events, then Event Sourcing is the principle where you store those list of events in an append-only style against the Aggregate's ID, rather than storing a snapshot of the Aggregate after the command was successfully handled.

To load an aggregate from the event store, you load all it's previous events, and replay them in memory on the Aggregate object, again rather than loading a single row/document in as a snapshot/memento.

A document database is therefore an excellent choice for event stores, because a single document represents the event stream for a given Aggregate. However if you want to store your event streams in SQL, that's fine, but you might store it in two tables:

```
create table Aggregate (Id int not null...);
create table AggregateEvent(AggregateId int not null FK..., Version int not null, eventBody nvarchar(max));
```

The actual event body would typically be the event itself, serialised to a text format like JSON.

## Projections and Read Stores

If you take the events generated by the handling of commands by aggregates, and write code that consumes them by writing to a separate data store (SQL, pre-calculated ViewModels, etc), then you can call that a "projection". It's "projecting" the data that's in one shape into another shape fit for a different purpose. The result is a "read store", which you can then query however you need to.